# Error in checkout a remote server in Git

Tags: git, git-checkout, remote-branch

I have cloned a remote Git server. but when I want to checkout it with the below code it give me error:

```
$ git checkout master origin/master
  error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Here's output of git branch:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master

$ git branch
  * master
```

How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to checkout the master branch, just run:

`git checkout master`

Immediately after a clone, your local master branch fully reflects the remote(i.e. origin/master) so you don't need to try and reference the remote when checking out